# How to print a map in systematic format is Scala

Tags: scala, formatting

I have a map and am trying to print it in systematic format, but got stuck.  I wanted a result like below. I'm very new in Scala.

```
val mapTest =
    Map(RedDef -> List(Map(RedTypP -> ^.{14}XY.*$, RedTypC -> XY, ExpNoOfAt -> 19, attributes -> List(Map(AttId -> 1, AttNa -> Pro Ty, AttMaxLen -> 1, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN)), Map(AttId -> 2, AttNa -> Pro Cod, AttMaxLen -> 6, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN)), Map(AttId -> 3, AttNa -> REQ CODE, AttMaxLen -> 7, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN))), RedLen -> 117, RedDeIn -> 2, MinNoOfAt -> 19), Map(RedTypP -> ^.{14}JK.*$, RedTypC -> JK, ExpNoOfAt -> 10, attributes -> List(Map(AttId -> 1, AttNa -> Log Si Ty, AttMaxLen -> 1, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> A)), Map(AttId -> 2, AttNa -> Log Si Cod, AttMaxLen -> 6,PassValidation->List(00000000) DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN)), RedDeIn -> 3, MinNoOfAt -> 10), Map(RedTypP -> ^.{14}FK.*$, RedTypC -> FK, ExpNoOfAt -> 33, attributes -> List(Map(AttId -> 1, AttNa -> Pro Ty, AttMaxLen -> 1, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN)), Map(AttId -> 2, AttNa -> Pro Cod, AttMaxLen -> 6, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN)), Map(AttId -> 3, AttNa -> REQ CDE, AttMaxLen -> 7, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN)), Map(AttId -> 4, AttNa -> RED Ty, AttMaxLen -> 2, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN))), RedLen -> 117, RedDeIn -> 4, MinNoOfAt -> 33)))
```

I wanted output like:

```
RedTypP = ^.{14}XY.*$
RedTypC = XY
ExpNoOfAt = 19
AttId = 1
AttNa = Pro Ty
AttMaxLen =1
DataTyName = AN
AttId = 2
AttNa = Pro Cod
AttMaxLen = 6
PassValidation=00000000
DataName = AN
RedTypP = "JK.*$"
RedTypC = JK
ExpNoOfAt = 10
AttId = 1
AttNa = Log Si Ty
AttMaxLen = 1
DataTyName = AN
RedLen = 117
RedDeIn = 2
MinNoOfAt =10
```

Answer (score 1):

Please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about asking good questions here on SO.

After that see how close this gets you to your goal.

```
def map2str(m: Map[String,_]): String = {
  m.map{
    case (_:String,v:List[Map[String,_]]) => v.map(map2str).mkString
    case (_:String,v:Map[String,_])       => map2str(v)
    case (k:String,v:String)              => s"$k = $v\n"
    case x                                => s"unknown: $x\n"
  }.mkString
}
```

Comment: jwvh thanks for your replay basically I don't want use println statement in printmap method. Whenever I want to access printmap method like println(printmap(mapTest)) then only it print the result.

Comment: @user1363308; Trivial change. Have a look.

Comment: jwvh, I'm getting this  error java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map

Comment: @user1363308; That's curious. I don't see where a `String`->`Map` cast might be coming from. The code passes my tests but I had to make some assumptions about your test data before it could be compiled. If you could post a **minimal** data example that causes the error, and post it **with the quote marks intact**, so that I can copy-paste it directly, I'll see to fixing it.